# Group of $\mathfrak a$-torsion points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

Silverman defines the **Group of $\mathfrak a$-torsion points** of an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb C$ (with $\mathfrak a$ an ideal in $\mathrm{End}(E)$) in *Advanced topics of elliptic curves* as
$$E[\mathfrak a] = \{P\in E\::\: [\alpha] P = 0 \text{ for all } \alpha \in \mathfrak a\}$$
This seems to be a generalization of $E[m]$ for $m\in \mathbb Z$.

But I don't get it.

Multiplication by $m$ is obviously the $m$-fold addition of $P$ with respect to the group law on $E$. But what would be $[i]P$ for a point on an elliptic curve with CM by $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: Do you know an elliptic curve with CM by $\mathbf Z[i]$? What is an automorphism of order 4 on that curve?

Comment: By the way, I just notice that since $i$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z[i]$, that might not be the most enlightening example to get an idea of how the construction works.

Comment: So like $y^2=x^3+x$ ... ?

Comment: Right. But in this context it might be easier to think of the curve as $\mathbf C/\Lambda$ for a suitable lattice $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

As Nefertiti pointed out, since $i$ is a unit in whatever ring it sits in, it’s less useful to ask about $i$-torsion points. But let’s take the curve $E:\,y^2=x^3-x$, which does have an automorphism $[i]$, namely $[i](x,y)=(-x,-iy)$. Then you might ask for $E[1+i]$, and that’s just the set of points $P$ on $E$ for which $P+[i](P)=\Bbb O$